# "Uncaught TypeError XXX is undefined" in a method but not in the constructor

Tags: javascript

I declare a class which begins like this:

```
class Editor {
    constructor() {
        this.note_text = document.getElementById("note_text");
        this.note_preview = document.getElementById('note_preview');
        this.cloze_type = document.getElementById("cloze_type");
        this.cloze_id = document.getElementById("cloze_id");
        this.span_debug = document.getElementById("span_debug");
        this.card_selection = document.getElementById('card_selection');
        this.mode = document.querySelector('input[name="preview_mode"]:checked');
        console.log(this.mode.value);

        this.note_text.oninput = this.display_update;
    }

    display_update() {
        let mode = this.mode.value;
[...]
```

Anytime `display_update()` is called, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: this.mode is undefined` on the line `let mode = this.mode.value;`. However, the line `console.log(this.mode.value);` just after the declaration of `this.mode` outputs the proper result.

How is it possible to have `this.mode` defined in the constructor, but not in a method ?

Comment: Most likely because `this` isn't what you think it is when you call `display_update`. How are you calling `display_update`?

Comment: When called from outside the class the code works. But I get this error when this.note_text.oninput is triggered.

Comment: How is it possible? When the calling context is not within the class instance

Comment: @vkubicki My bad, I missed that in your code. Yes, that's a problem since `this` will not refer to the object anymore. To see why, Guy Incognito's link gives an explanation (addEventListener is similar to oninput assignment there)

Comment: Thank everyone, sorry for the duplicate, I accepted the redirection.